# Java String formatting

Tags: java, string, properties

I have a property-file with strings inside, formatted in this way:

```
audit.log.events.purged=The audit events were purged. {0} events were purged, {1} assets were deleted.
```

Is there a way to bind some values inside those **{0}** and **{1}**, using some standard APIs, or should I create some code for parsing those Strings?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for MessageFormat: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html

Answer (score 11):

Java 1.4.2:

```
String formattedMessage = MessageFormat.format(message, new Object[]{parm1, parm2});
```

Java 1.5+:

```
String formattedMessage = MessageFormat.format(message, parm1, parm2);
```

In both cases you can have as many parameters as you wish, not just two.

Comment: Actually, it will work as MessageFormat.format(message, parm1, parm2); as well, cause it accepts enumerations.

Comment: Correct - I'm unfortunately still far too used to programming with 1.4's retrictions!